# Template Flicker with Meteorjs

Tags: javascript, templates, user-interface, meteor

I'm getting a flicker of a conditional login template inside my admin template.

so with a url of `http://0.0.0.0:3000/admin` and the following admin template:

```
<template name="admin">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns">
      {{#if currentUser}}
        <h2>Admin Panel</h2>
        <p><a href="/">View Site</a></p>
      {{else}}
        {{> login}}
      {{/if}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Every time I visit that url, the login template flickers for a millisec before properly rendering the admin template. Any ideas on what's going here? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
{{#if currentUser}}
  <h2>Admin Panel</h2>
  <p><a href="/">View Site</a></p>
{{else}}
  {{#unless loggingIn}}
    {{> login}}
  {{/unless}}
{{/if}}
```

While the user is still logging in, `currentUser` will be falsy and your `else` case will render. To fix this, you can guard the login template with [loggingIn](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_loggingin).